# In dataframe iam getting unexpected results

Tags: pandas, dataframe

when i have tried with below code iam getting unexpected results.
This is my code:
    def copy_blanks(df, column):

```
    df.iloc[:, -1] = df.iloc[:, column]
    df.loc[df.iloc[:, column] == '', -1] = ''

My input file:
word,number
abc,0
adf,0
gfsgs,0
,0
sdfgsd,0
fgsdfg,0
sfdgs,0

Iam getting like below output:
word,number,word_clean
NA,0,abc
NA,0,adf
NA,0,gfsgs
,0,
NA,0,sdfgsd
NA,0,fgsdfg
NA,0,sfdgs

I Want to get like below output:
word,number,word_clean
abc,0,abc
adf,0,adf
gfsgs,0,gfsgs
,0,
sdfgsd,0,sdfgsd
fgsdfg,0,fgsdfg
sfdgs,0,sfdgs
```

PLease suggest me.I think the issue is getting by this code [df.loc[df.iloc[:, column] == '', -1] = ''].

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you need [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replacing `NaN` to empty string:

```
print (df)
     word  number
0     abc       0
1     adf       0
2   gfsgs       0
3     NaN       0
4  sdfgsd       0
5  fgsdfg       0
6   sfdgs       0

def copy_blanks(df, column):
    df['new'] = df.iloc[:, column]
    df['new'] = df['new'].fillna('')
    return df

column = 0  
print (copy_blanks(df, column))    
     word  number     new
0     abc       0     abc
1     adf       0     adf
2   gfsgs       0   gfsgs
3     NaN       0        
4  sdfgsd       0  sdfgsd
5  fgsdfg       0  fgsdfg
6   sfdgs       0   sfdgs
```

Comment: I am not sure what need exactly, because if empty string in copied column, then `df.loc[df.iloc[:, column] == '', -1] = ''` is not necessary. Or am I something missing?